# How can I configure ssl for different ports?

Tags: nginx, ssl

My application runs on 2 ports client (3000) and server (8080). I was able to set up ssl for the client but cannot for the server. As a result, I am having problems, I cannot make requests from the https client to the http server.

Server accepts api requests along the route / api / *, and gives images along the route to this / products / {id} / *.
that is, I execute all requests to the server like this  `host:8080/api/*` or `host:8080/products/{id}/{name}.jpg`

Config nginx:

```
server {
    server_name xxx www.xxx;
    root /var/www/xxx;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
     }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxu/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = xxx) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name xxx www.xxx
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I tried searching the internet for information and supplementing the config, but it didn't work.

```
server {
    server_name xxx www.xxx;
    root /var/www/xxx;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    listen 8080 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxu/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Sorry, I am not an expert in this area and I am asking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding proxying from localhost: 8080 / api to domain / api and domain / products from localhost: 8080 / products